# Trying to simulate a jump process in discrete time

Tags: python, simulation, probability, distribution, sampling

I was trying to simulate a jump process in python, defined as follows:

[image]

Actually, in order to simulate the process, I evaluate its value at each time `t`, building an "history" of the values the process has taken. This is done accordingly to the following function, contained in a class:

```py
def evaluate(self, t):
        try:
            return self.history[t], {} # History of the process
        except:
            new_steps = t - len(self.history) # Calculate how much steps will be evaluated in order to reach t
            values_to_sample = 1 + new_steps
            new_values = np.zeros(values_to_sample)
            temp = self.history[-1] # Take last seen value
            for i in range(values_to_sample):
                temp = temp + self.A*( UNKNOWN TERM - temp ) + np.random.normal(scale=self.sigma) 
            # UNKNOWN TERM is the element that I want to "simulate"
                new_values[i] = temp
            self.history = np.concatenate((self.history, new_values))
            return self.history[t], {}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to simulate the `Yt` term. To my understanding, what I should do is evaluate at each new sample if a jump has occurred, but I do not know how to do that. Can someone help me understand what should I do?